# Append to formData not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, append

I'm sending formData holds array after appending the array to the formData. But when I debug in the controller I'm getting the whole data except the list. So I'm wondering did I made any mistake with code. Because in the source debug I hadn't any error in the appending of the array. The exact problem is with the append because i tried to append an text area and still the append won't work

below is the javascript code

```
function SubmitForm(form) {
    RoleCapabilities = new Array();

    $('#destinationItems option').each(function () {
        var RoleCapability = {
            "Id": "", "RoleId": "", "CapabilityId": "",
            "AccessFlagId": "", "InsertedDate": "", "InsertUserId": "",
            "UpdateUserId": "", "UpdatedDate": ""
        };
        RoleCapability.Id = 0;
        RoleCapability.CapabilityId = this.value;
        RoleCapability.RoleId = 1;
        RoleCapability.AccessFlagId = 1;
        RoleCapability.InsertedDate = getDate(new Date());
        RoleCapability.InsertUserId = 1;
        RoleCapability.UpdatedDate = getDate(new Date());
        RoleCapability.UpdateUserId = 1;

        RoleCapabilities.push(RoleCapability);
    })

    debugger;

    $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(form);
    var formData = new FormData($(form)[0]);
    var json_arr = JSON.stringify(RoleCapabilities);


    formData.append('RoleCapabilities', json_arr);
    formData.append('RoleName', 'test');


    if ($(form).valid()) {
        $.ajax({
            type: form.method,
            url: form.action,
            //"datatype": "json"
            data: formData,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.success) {
                    Popup.dialog('close');
                    dataTable.ajax.reload();

                    $.notify(data.message, {
                        globalPosition: "top center",
                        className: "success"
                    })

                } else {
                    Popup.dialog('close');

                    $.notify(data.message, {
                        globalPosition: "top center",
                        className: "error"
                    })
                }
            }
        });
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please provide a working example.  SO allows you to insert and run HTML/JavaScript/CSS into your question.  You may even find some issues along the way.

Comment: A little old.  May still help: https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Comment: Ok thank you so much I'll take a look